# What kind of light fixture connector is this? What can I replace this with?

Tags: wiring, lighting, recessed-lighting, connectors

I've got some recessed downlight fixtures at my place that have these three extra wires with a weird looking circle connector.  All of the light fixtures in the building have a 2 wire connector, but only a few of them also have these 3 wire ones.  I was hoping to find another light fixture with the same connectors but with a light warmness of 5000K.  Does anyone know what I could replace it with? Or at the very least does anyone know what kind of connector the one on the bottom left of the photo is (the one with the red, blue and black wires)?
[image]

Comment: The ones that only have a two wire connector, what does it connect to?  Are they retrofitted in older recessed fixtures, using adapters that screw into the old bulb sockets?  And plugged into those?  And what else is different about the ones with the extra connector?

Comment: there's a metal housing cylinder that's blocking my view of the entirety of the connections, but i'm about 90% sure the two wire connector connects to a light bulb socket.  Apparently it's called a E26 adapter? RMDman seems to know what it is...  So yes, I believe your correct; they are retrofitted recessed fixtures, using screw-in adapters.  The only thing I can think of that stands out to me about the extra connector is that it has 3 wires (red, black, and blue) and is wired to the LED driver, not the bulb.

Comment: Proprietary? **What is the name of this light fixture's connector?** +1.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the terminology of these things, so I can't say for sure. From what others are saying, the 2 wire connector is an "Edison adapter" which connects to a standard screw-on bulb socket; the 3 wire connector is for a battery back-up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The orange connector upper most in the picture connects to an "Edison adapter", or a lead that screws into a standard bulb socket.

The other orange lead is to be connected to a battery back up if supplied.

"All of the light fixtures in the building..."  This tells me you are in a commercial building, or multi-family, like a condo or apartment. There lights in the common areas can be required to have battery backup.  It further makes sense that the builder or electrical sub contractor would purchase lights in greater quantities for the discount and use the same in common areas and in units as well.

Comment: Plausible. Why three wires?

Comment: @Jay613,  Guessing that there is some type of relay from one light to another?  I just found from the manufacturer that the light had battery back up available and knew the DC had to be separate from the AC.

Comment: @jay613: red +v, blue gnd (aka -v), black earth for the chassis. Or if it is for a battery, the 3rd is temp sensor (middle leg of resistor dividers with a thermistor on one half), like a cell phone battery.

Comment: @RMDman yes that seems about right.  Next to one of those fixtures has an emergency power indicator panel (small panel with a red light).  The building I'm in right now has a second floor that's above a shop.  I'm guessing at some point the second floor was used commercially?

Although that battery backup connector is making finding a replacement difficult.  2 of the 3 fixtures are pretty much dead or near dead.  I can't seem to find a place that sells fixtures that match what I want AND have that extra connector.  Any idea on what I could do?

Comment: If you don't know what the extra connector is for, or if it is for emergency battery power that you no longer have and do not need, you can replace the fixture with any retrofit one that will physically fit in the ceiling. If you do need emergency backup, in a commercial or multifamily setting, this forum isn't for those kinds of questions.

Answer (score 3):

The orange plug goes into the orange socket. The light fitting plugs into the driver. They are a marched pair.

You can't necessarily mix and match. Your other fitting may not need a driver.

Comment: Yeah, mix n'match driver/light combos is highly unlikely to work out.

Comment: Downvoting, maybe prematurely, but the two connectors do not appear to match, and something must connect to a power source, and the driver does not seem to be the kind that you open up and use a knockout to connect AC. So most probably, one of these is DC power, and the other is something else, IDK 10V dimming? A guess. The manufacturer's website doesn't help.

Comment: what orange socket? obviously the DC out and the AC in are shown, there's no visible socket.